# ./gradlew installDist Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: gradle

I am trying to test ./gradlew installDist task.

Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Users\Sandeep Prajapati\Downloads\Ex_Files_Gradle_Java\Exercise Files\chapter_1\01_01\build\install\01_01\bin\01_01.bat1_01_OPTSCLASSPATH*
The system cannot find the path specified

Project structure
[image]

build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

mainClassName = 'com.linkedinlearning.calculator.Main'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

version = '1.0.0'

compileJava{
    options.compilerArgs << '-Werror'
}

jar {
    archiveBaseName = 'calculator'
}

application {
    mainClass = 'com.linkedinlearning.calculator.Main'
}

enter code here
```

the command i ran is /install/01_01/bin ~ ./01_01 add 1 2

Answer (score 0):

the jar task , archiveBaseName was mismatching with the rootProject name, the issue was resolved by adding rootProject.name = 'calculator' in settings.gradle